# C# Aforge - Webcam picture file size too big

Tags: c#, aforge

Picture save from my webcam in about 20 > 25 KB.
I use Aforge to capture webcam picture for my app. This is code:

```
    void Device_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        String fileName = "webcam.jpg";
        img.Save("Data\\WC\\" + fileName);
        img.Dispose();
        webcam.SignalToStop();
    }

    static int Main()
    {
        fic = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        webcam = new VideoCaptureDevice(fic[0].MonikerString);
        webcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Device_NewFrame);
        webcam.Start();
    }
```

I get picture size 500 > 700 KB. How can I modify output file size if I use Aforge?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replace line:

```
img.Save("Data\\WC\\" + fileName);
```

with:

```
img.Save("Data\\WC\\" + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```